# What is start faster by ignoring the start-up file?

Tags: shell, unix

What is different between /bin/tcsh and /bin/tcsh -f ?
I create environment variables before I run a script. How does 'f' effect ?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for tcsh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh) has the answer you are looking for:

> When a command to be executed is found not to be a builtin command the
>   shell attempts to execute the command via execve(2). Each word in the
>   variable path names a directory in which the shell will look for the
>   command. If the shell is not given a -f option, the shell hashes the
>   names in these directories into an internal table so that it will try
>   an execve(2) in only a directory where there is a possibility that the
>   command resides there. This greatly speeds command location when a
>   large number of directories are present in the search path. This
>   hashing mechanism is not used: ... 2. If the shell was given a -f argument.

Comment: What is your recommendation  ? Can you give me example ? @hikerjobs

Comment: As Jean-Baptiste said, for most cases, you probably don't need to worry about this. Only if you have a lot of commands that are not built-in would you need to start thinking about performance issues. Also, I don't think it's referring to environment variables when it says builtin commands. Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you give me example ? When must I use without f ? @hikerjobs

Comment: Sorry I don't use tcsh much to be able to give you an example. You could just try both with and without -f and see if you notice any perceptible difference. If not, go without -f because it's fewer characters to type. But why are you using tcsh instead of say, bash?